# ActiveSheet property returns a Worksheet Object. But Still I cant use the NAME property directly. Why?

Tags: excel, vb.net, com

To get the name of the Active sheet in the workbook `owb` I have to first return the Worksheet value returned by `owb.Activesheet` in `osh` which is a worksheet type variable. Then I can access the Name property by writing: `osh.Name`. However when I try to write `owb.ActiveSheet.Name` it does not work. But clearly `owb.ActiveSheet` returns a Worksheet object - then why I am not able to access the NAME property directly when I write `owb.ActiveSheet.Name`. I have also attached an image showing the intellisense drop down that comes when this - as you may see the NAME property does not appear.

```
Imports System
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Module Program
    Dim oxl As Excel.Application
    Dim owb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim osheet, osh As Excel.Worksheet
    Sub Main(args As String())
        oxl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        oxl.Visible = True
        owb = oxl.Workbooks.Add
        osheet = owb.Worksheets.Add(, , 5,)
        osh = owb.ActiveSheet
        Console.WriteLine("Active Sheet: {0}", osh.Name)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

[Intellisense drop down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcdxF.png)

Comment: Can you clarify *"it does not work"?*  Are you getting an error? An unexpected result in  `osheet.Name`? Also, maybe see "[ask]" as well as "how to create a [mcve]".

Comment: @ashleedawg no error in `osheet.name`. I want to print the name of Active sheet that is getting returned in `owb.ActiveSheet`. And this I am unabe to do. `owb.ActiveSheet.Name` does not work. So wanted to know the workaround.  And yes, i do get your point on minimal reproducible example - shall keep in mind.